# Django: How can you index images from an object_list in a django template

Tags: python, django

So basically I wanted to know how you can index images in a django template using a for loop. The idea is to create a slide show using the first three images that you user has adds to the model

model.py

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    Category=models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    Image=models.ImageField(null=True,upload_to='Image')
    Description=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    Price=models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Delivery_date=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    Delivered=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is the template but the `obj.Image.url` tag is incomplete as I want only the first three items and not in a loop but listed out

```
{% for obj in object_list %}

{% if obj.Image %}
<ul class="pgwSlider">
    <li><img src="{{ obj.Image.url }}"></li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <span>Shanghai, China</span>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want just 3 images (maybe it's newest, right), you just deliver your own images context from view to template.

Maybe you're using `ListView`, then you have to use `get_context_data` to pass other context data.

this is simple usage for `get_context_data`. If you want more info, you can check [django official documents for simple mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) (Official docs are really helpful!)

**Your View example**

```
...
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourListView).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['top_three_images'] = [
        product.Image.url
        for product in Product.objects.exclude(Image=None)[:3]
    ]
    return context
```

> You can use your own code instead of list comprehension.

Then You can simply use `top_three_images` in template.
**Your Template**

```
    {% for image_url in top_three_images %}
    <img src="{{ image_url}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
```

> p.s. I recommend you to use your model field starting with lower_case (i.e. `name`, `category`, `image` ...)

### Update

You want to show just first three images inside the loop, right?

If I understand correctly, I think `foorloop.coutner` maybe helps.

In html, you can use `{% if forloop.counter < 4 %}` (forloop starts with `1`)

```
{% for obj in object_list %}

{% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
<ul class="pgwSlider">
    <li><img src="{{ obj.Image.url }}"></li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <span>Shanghai, China</span>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hoping helpful.

Comment: + If you want to use only top 3 of object_list, you can use your own template_tag (for example, range) and use it in templae. If you need more help, leave a comment. I hope it helps!

Comment: 1. If you want only products with images, use `for product in Product.objects.exclude(Image=None)[:2]

Comment: 2. If you want to use other properties of the products, use instead `context['top_three_products_with_images'] = [product for product in…`.

Comment: Thank you the reply but i had done that. The problem is that instead of a loop i basically wanted to spread the images out...like img_url.1, img_url.2,, img.3 in the template

Comment: Can you describe more? You mean that you want to use only 3 images while looping, right?

Comment: yes but instead of a loop i would want the first three images the user uploaded to be saved in three variables that i can used in the template.

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved this with the help of template tag.Basically i created

```
from django import template
from Products.models import Product

register=template.Library()

@register.filter
def id_check(value,arg):
    arg=arg+value
    context=Product.objects.get(id=arg)

    return context.Image.url
```

and ran only one loop in the template

```
{% for obj in object_list %}

{% if forloop.first %}


<ul class="pgwSlider">

    <li><img src="{{ obj.id|id_check:0}}" alt="Montral, QC, Canada" data-large-src="{{ obj.id|id_check:1}}"></li>
    <li><img src="{{ obj.id|id_check:1}}" alt="Canada" data-large-src="{{ obj.id|id_check:2}}" ></li>
    <li><img src="{{obj.id|id_check:2}}" alt="Montral, QC, Canada" data-large-src="{{ obj.id|id_check:10}}"></li>
    <li><img src="{{ obj.id|id_check:3}}" alt="Canada" data-large-src="{{ obj.id|id_check:7}}"></li>


</ul>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```